# How to create a listener on a JMS Temporary Queue in a JEE server (Wildfly)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, wildfly

I'm trying to create a temporary JMS queue using JMS 2.0 in Wildfly 10, and an injected connection factory.

I am injecting my ConnectionFactory using @JMSConnectionFactory.  This works fine.

```
@Inject @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory") JMSContext jmsContext
```

Creating a temporary queue also works fine:

```
Destination jmsQueue = jmsContext.createTemporaryQueue();
```

Creating a publisher and publishing messages works okay as well:

```
JMSProducer producer = jmsContext.createProducer();
TextMessage msg = jmsContext.createTextMessage(Long.toString(new Date().getTime()));
producer.send(jmsQueue, msg);
```

However, how do I create a listener for the queue?  I cannot use an MDB as the temp queue is not predefined.  If I try to create a consumer, and assign a message listener to it, I get the following error message:

```
    JMSConsumer consumer = jmsContext.createConsumer(jmsQueue);
    consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                 ...
                 ...
            });
```

Error trace:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: This method is not applicable inside the application server. See the J2EE spec, e.g. J2EE1.4 Section 6.6
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASession.checkStrict(ActiveMQRASession.java:1452)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAMessageConsumer.setMessageListener(ActiveMQRAMessageConsumer.java:123)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConsumer.setMessageListener(ActiveMQJMSConsumer.java:59)
```

So it appears that I cannot explicity set a message listener with a JEE controlled connection factory. But given that it is a temp queue, I cannot create an MDB since the Destination is not known at compile time.  So how do I listen to a temp queue?

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to solve this problem by using JMS 1.0.  I had code something like:

```
TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory;
Topic topic;
TopicConnection topicConnection;

try {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory)jndi.lookup("jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory");
    topic = (Topic)jndi.lookup("jms/myTopicName");

    topicConnection = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();

    TopicSession topicSession = topicConnection.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    TopicSubscriber topicSubscriber = topicSession.createSubscriber(projectTopic, null, false);
    topicSubscriber.setMessageListener(listenerClass);
    topicConnection.start();
}
...
```

where `listenerClass` is a class that implements `javax.jms.MessageListener`.

This takes advantage of the predefined JMS connection factory defined in Wildfly within `standalone-full.xml` so that I don't need to set up an explicit one.

As a warning - the last I ran this code was in Wildfly 8 so some things may have changed a bit.  Additionally, I wasn't using remote connections so, again, there may be some differences.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that as well, but still getting the same exception thrown.  Not particularly surprised since the Client is still using the same ActiveMARASession whether it is using JMS2 or JMS1 facade.   I can't imagine that there isn't a logical solution to this.

Comment: Why do you need a temporary queue at all? If you are expecting the container to supply mdb instances for the lifetime of the deployment, then that also requires the queue to exist, else what would they attach to?

Comment: @willt I need to have a publish/subscribe queue that is unique to each node in my cluster.  The queue had to live for the lifespan of the runtime; it does not need to persist restarts.  Plus I don't want to have to manage these queues manually.    Hence the idea of a temporary queue... But if there is no way to listen to it, then what is the purpose of a temp queue at all in jee?

Comment: @EricB. - what is your deployment environment like?  I ended up getting rid of my JMS code in favor of AWS SQS queues.  It's not 100% replacement as the SQS queues need to be polled but for my code it worked well.

Comment: @stdunbar Jboss EAP 7/ Wildfly 10. Moving to third party mq broker not an option at tous point in time, but think it Will become in the future. But need a solution for right now